# Write to file last twenty(20) results

Tags: java, android, sql

I am sending data via bluetooth from first device to second device in my android application. This information I write to text file. But I need only last twenty 20 results. So how I can do this? I think using SQLite... and reading from SQLite table last results... Maybe I can do this using other way? Please help me... It's my testing code write data into the file:

```
try {

        String test = "test\n";
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "dir/file.txt");
            byteGet = test.getBytes();

        writeToFile = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        writeToFole.write(byteGet);

        } catch (Exception e) {   
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the behavior you want using a fixed-size circular queue that allows random reads or dumps a la `toArray()`. Here are a couple that should fit the bill:

- [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) (Apache Commons)
- [EvictingQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) (Google Guava)